# Is this an Australian Wolf Spider? Any idea on the species if so?

Tags: species-identification, arthropod

I live in Western Australia, and recently have been finding a lot of a particular type of spider out in my backyard (generally at night, on the lawn).

From what I could find, I believe it is an [Australian Wolf Spider](https://australian.museum/learn/animals/spiders/wolf-spiders/), but wanted to make sure by asking here, as I was suggested to do so, [when trying to find out how dangerous they are to small dogs](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/35600/16628).

Here is a pic of one I managed to capture (in a glass pasta sauce jar for size reference), the spiders are about 25mm - 50mm big I'd say.

[image]

Here is a close-up:

[image]

I have also being seeing the tell-tale sign of small little burrows in the ground for awhile now, which [seems to be what they do](https://australian.museum/learn/animals/spiders/wolf-spiders/).

As I understand it, there are many many species of Wolf Spiders, and from this [Reddit question](https://www.quora.com/How-should-you-treat-a-wolf-spiders-bite-on-a-dog) a couple of people explain them quite differently to the spider I am seeing, eg;

```
The wolf spider is big, hairy and scary looking

Wolf spiders, though rather large and fearsome
```

Is this an Australian Wolf Spider, and if so, any idea on the species?

Comment: A closer-up photo showing its eyes clearly would help with identification.

Comment: @timeskull I have added a close-up, that's as close as I can get with the current shot. If you need closer, I would need to capture another one and take another photo. Cheers!

Comment: This observation might be suitable for [iNaturalist](https://www.inaturalist.org).

Comment: @AgnesianOperator Interesting. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is *Lycosa australicola*.

Found across the central and west of Australia.

Other species I have not yet checked that occur there (from wikipedia entry on lycosa, from the World Spider Catalog) are:
ariadnae
corallina
cowlei
dimota
gibsoni
hickmani
koyuga
salifodina
tula
woonda
yalkara

[image]

Comment: Thanks - though the colouring does seem a bit differently placed on mine?

Comment: I haven’t checked the whole list. It might be a new one.

Comment: How about you go through the list? If it’s a new species you can name it after me.

Comment: Way to many to go through lol

Answer (score 0):

it's an Australian wolf spider, based on:

- striped back
- long hairy legs
  so we can deduce it's an Australian wolf spider.

Comment: There are many spiders that fit the description of "long hairy legs, striped back". Your answer could be improved by adding something more specific, with the citation of a reference or two.